# Hide item after deleting it with ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my asp.net mvc4 application, I have a portfilio list , i use ajax to delete portfolio items, I want to hide the

```
<li>
```

that its item has been deleted. How can i achive this. This is my view:

```
<ul >
@foreach (var item in Model.Portfolios)
{
    <li >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">                  
            </div>                                  
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", "Admin", new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "post",
                    OnBegin = "beginRequest",
                    OnComplete = "endRequest",
                    OnSuccess = "successRequest",
                    OnFailure = "failRequest"

                }))
                {                                
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" value=@item.PortfolioId id="id" name="id" />
                        <input type="submit" value="delete" >
                    </div>
                }                                      
        </div>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Is best practice using Jquery? if yes how can i access to

```
<li>
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: you need something like a class, data attribute on the li or within it to do a jquery selector for that li. say you add a class 'deleted' to the li, then it would be $('li.deleted')

Comment: there is another question , how to apply 'deleted' class to li in runtime?

Comment: in your successRequest javascript function. making the assumption that if the item is deleted then the OnSuccess function is reached. check this question for more on it's use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691810/ajax-beginform-onsuccess-get-event-target

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jquery is a good solution for this:

In your HTMl you will need to add an Id or a unique value to your list element

```
<li id="@item.Id">
```

In your sucessRequest pass the Id of the element you are in

```
 OnSuccess = "successRequest("+item.Id+")",
```

On your sucessRequest you need to do the action of hiding which is adding a class or just hiding it

```
function  successRequest(itemId){
$('#'+itemId).hide();
}
```